# Passing parameter to controller function from jQuery function '$.ajax'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using ASPNET MVC 2.0. I'm trying to pass a value from View to Controller function using jquery function .ajax. My jquery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Search").click(function(event) {

        var searchString = $("#TraderSearch").val();            
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Build/SearchTrader',
            data: "{strData : '" + searchString + "' }",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(ResultList) {
                var contents = "";
                var count = 0;
                $(ResultList).each(function() {
                contents = contents + '<tr><td>' + ResultList[count].Name + '</td><td>' + ResultList[count].Value +
                     '</td><td><a class="edit"><img src="../../html/images/Edit.gif" width="14" height="14" alt="edit" /></a></td></tr>';
                    count = count + 1;
                });
                $("#SerachResultList").append(contents);
                alert("{strData : '" + searchString + "' }");
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);

            }
        });


    });
});
```

And my Controller function is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult SearchTrader(string strData)
    {


        //Function to search DB based on the string passed

        return Json(lstDictObject);
    }
```

My problem is that, I am not able to get the value in my controller. I'm getting strData as 'null'. I think there is somme mistake in the way i'm trying to pass the value? Can anyone correct me?

Thanks in Advance,

Vipin Menon

Comment: Try valid JSON: `'{"strData": "' + searchString + '" }'`, any difference?

Comment: it could be a routing issue. the default is 'probably' set to id. a new route may help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data: "strData = " + searchstring
```

Comment: Not my vote, but this isn't correct on several levels, the extra spacing and lack of encoding mainly

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
data: { strData: searchstring }
```

Quotes caused the same issue in the script I just tested.

You also need to check the spelling on your "#SerachResultList" if this is your actual code.